# Basic Ruby Table of Contents Alignment

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to make a table of contents where the Chapters are on the left side; and the corresponding page numbers are justified on the right side.

Here is my code:

```
lineWidth = 60
str = "Table of Contents"
puts str.center lineWidth

chapters = ["Chapter 1: Numbers", "Chapter 2: Letters", "Chapter 3: Variables"] 
numbers = ["page: 1", "page: 72", "page: 118"]
puts chapters.ljust(lineWidth/2) + numbers.rjust(lineWidth/2)
```

Does anyone know why this is coming back as an error, when the following works:

```
# lineWidth = 60
# str = "test"
# puts str.ljust(lineWidth/2) + str.rjust(lineWidth/2)
```

Comment: Seems ghufran determined the problem, but please remember next time to include the actual error you're encountering, otherwise its up to us to guess what the actual problem is, and that's never good.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new myself, but the problem is that `chapters` is an array, and the method `ljust` is not defined for arrays. 
The following code works for `chapters`:

```
chapters.each {|t| puts t.ljust(lineWidth/2)}
```

And for `numbers`:

```
numbers.each {|t| puts t.rjust(lineWidth/2)}
```

The problem you then have is that you want each chapter on the same line. I don't think you can use the above technique with two separate arrays.

What you could do is put the chapters and numbers in the same array, like this:

```
toc = [
       ["Chapter 1: Numbers", "page: 1"],
       ["Chapter 2: Letters", "page: 72"],
       ["Chapter 3: Variables", "page: 118"],
      ]

toc.each do |t|
  puts t[0].ljust(lineWidth/2) + t[1].rjust(lineWidth/2)
end
```

This has the added advantage that each entry in toc has the chapter and page number 'packaged' together in an array, making it easier to add more chapters and page numbers without worrying about having each entry in chapters 'match up' with the corresponding entry in 'numbers'

By the way, you don't *need* the final comma after the third array (the one for chapter 3), but if you leave it there, ruby copes fine with it, and it makes it obvious what the next line should look like. Otherwise, when you add a fourth entry later, it's easy to forget to add the comma after the chapter 3 array, which will give you an error)